# How so i update the Entry When Razor Page DropDownListFor Changes with out JavaScript

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor, razor-pages

i want to change database entry when dropdownlistfor changes the value. 
how do i do it with out javascript. current code here.

```
<table class="table table-striped border">
                    <thead> --Table Header </thead>
                    @foreach (var dn in Model.Deliveries)
                    {
                        <tr>

                            <td>
                                    @Html.Hidden("LId", dn.Id)
                                    @Html.DropDownListFor(x =>
                                         dn.Deliverer, new SelectList(Model.Stafs, "Id", "FirstName"),
                                         htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control", id = "deliverer" })

                            </td>

                        </tr>
                    }
                </table>
```

[image: DDLF]

Comment: This `id = "deliverer"` shouldn't work. You'll be creating multiple dropdownlists with the same ID. HTML Id's have to be unique. Suffix it with a unique value such as `id="deliverer_@dn.Id"`

Answer (score 0):

Put the dropdown control inside a form and let it submit onchange, you can do either get or post reqest:

```html
<form method="get">
    @Html.Hidden("LId", dn.Id)
    @Html.DropDownListFor(x => dn.Deliverer, new SelectList(Model.Stafs, "Id", "FirstName"), htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control", id = "deliverer", onchange="this.form.submit()" })
</form>
```

It will submit to the same page so the page will reload when the dropdown changes.

Comment: the table is already on a form, and i am using OnPost method to get the results based on Dates.